# How can I add an image as the fill for a circle dynamically in javascript using d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a series of images, each with a date as a name.  I created a table using d3 (with a date on each row) and I'm trying to add the corresponding image to each row of the table.  I initially created a pattern and then added a circle with my image as the fill:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">


<style>

 td, th {
    padding: 4px 10px;
} 



</style>
<body>

    <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
        <p><strong>Total Steps</strong></p>
    </div>

<svg id="mySvg" width="0" height="0">   
  <defs id="mdef">
    <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" height="20" width="20">
      <image x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" xlink:href="images/2015-10-15.jpg"></image> 
     </pattern>
 </defs>
 </svg>   



<script src="d3.min.js"></script>


<script>


d3.csv("step_data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;


// render the table
 var daytaTable = tabulate(data, ["date", "steps", "pic1", "pic2"]);


});

function type(d) {
  d.steps = +d.steps;
  return d;
}

// The table generation function
function tabulate(data, columns) {
  var table = d3.select("body").append("table")
        .attr("style", "margin-left: 4px"),
    thead = table.append("thead"),
    tbody = table.append("tbody");

// append the header row
thead.append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append("th")
        .text(function(column) { return column; });

// create a row for each object in the data
var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("tr");


// create a cell in each row for each column
 var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(row) {
        return columns.map(function(column) {
            return {column: column, value: row[column]};
        });
    })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .attr("style", "font-family: Courier") // sets the font style
        .html(function(d) { return d.value; });


var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(row) {
        return columns.map(function(column) {
            return {column: column, value: row[column]};
        });
    })



    .filter(function(d){ return d.column == 'pic1'})
    .append(function(d) {
      return createSVG(d);
    });




  return table;


}



function createSVG(d) {


  var w = 30;
  var h = 30;

  var kpi = document.createElement("div");

  var svg = d3.select(kpi).append("svg")
    .attr({
      width: w,
      height: h
    });



  var elem = svg.selectAll("div")
    .data([d]);

  var elemEnter = elem.enter()
    .append("g");



  elemEnter.append("circle")

    .filter(function(d){ return d.column == 'pic1'})
    .attr({
      cx: 28,
      cy: 25,
      r: 20
    })


  //  .style("fill", "url(#image)");
  //  .style("fill", "url(images/2015-10-15.jpg")
      .style("fill", "red")


  return kpi;

  }


</script>
```

This only works if every row gets the same picture.  Is there a way to update the xlink:href dynamically from javascript and make each row independent?  Maybe a better option is to not use the pattern, but dynamically add the appropriate image to each row using another method?

Comment: You just want an image in a table cell?  Just use an `<img>` tag, no need for SVG here.

Comment: I'm probably making this more difficult than it needs to be, but I added the rest of the code.  The table itself is being generated from a .csv file.

Comment: If you want your code debugged, please post a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead.  If you just want a general explanation, don't post code; just explain it better.

Comment: I don't need code debugged as the code I posted works.  I just need to know how to put a different image in each row dependent upon the "date" column of my table.  It currently applies a color (red) or the same image on every row.

I'm creating this table from a .csv file.  The CSV file has the first two columns (including the date) and I have a corresponding .jpg for each date.  I want to add each corresponding .jpg to the third column of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand your problem, date is just a key in an array of image paths. The following code changes the `fill` attribute of each circle, in function of its index `i` in the data. It should be a good start to solve your problem.

```js
var images = ["img1.png","img2.png","img3.png"];

d3.selectAll("circle")
   .data(images)
     .enter()
   .style("fill",function(d,i){ return "url(" + d + ")"; });
```

[This](http://d3js.org/#enter-exit) is a good reading regarding the use of d3 `enter` and `exit`

Comment: Thanks for sending along the reading.  I still need to return the date dynamically, but this helped steer me in the right direction.